# Разброс чисел в php

Tags: php

Крч имеется например такой код:

```
$a = rand(1.100);
$b = rand(1.100);
if ($a ==$b) {
echo "Вы победили";
```

Как сделать так, чтобы условие выполнялось если разброс чисел например 10, т.е если $а = 40 , а $b= 50 либо $b= 49 и т.д, то выводило также сообщение о том, что я победил? 
Может есть какая специальная функция для этого?

Comment: у вас ошибка в коде:  `rand(1.100);` что вообще значит? rand принимает или 2 параметра или ноль параметров

Comment: Я в курсе, там запятая должна быть, чет шифт не дожал. Да и не суть в коде.

Answer (score 3):

Очевидно же, посчитать разницу и сравнить с 10 (без учёта знака):

```
if( abs($a - $b) <= 10 ) {
  echo "Вы победили";
}
```

P.S. Только сначала правильно `rand()` надо вызвать, а не так, как у вас.

Comment: А как в следующем if  далее сделать разброс от 11 до 20?

Comment: @gottar rand уже deprecated, лучше mt_rand

Comment: @TheCold, э... не совсем понял, что мешает проверить, попадает ли разница в диапазон от 11 до 20?

Comment: @TheCold сделать составное условие чтобы модуль разницы был от 11 до 20.

Comment: Блин, туплю что-то страшно. Сделал уже. Всем спасибо.